# WSO2 EMM Error occurred while registering the OAuth application : emm

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I was able to successfully setup WSO2EMM server with H2 database. Now trying to setup database as postgresl.

While login to EMM server https://localhost/emm I am getting the folowing exception.

```
[2016-05-20 14:04:31,412] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dynamic.client.web.app.registration.DynamicClientWebAppRegistrationManager} -  Error occurred while registering the OAuth application : emm
org.wso2.carbon.dynamic.client.registration.DynamicClientRegistrationException: Can not create OAuth application  : emm
at org.wso2.carbon.dynamic.client.registration.impl.DynamicClientRegistrationServiceImpl.registerOAuthApplication(DynamicClientRegistrationServiceImpl.java:87)
at org.wso2.carbon.dynamic.client.web.app.registration.util.DynamicClientWebAppRegistrationUtil.registerOAuthApplication(DynamicClientWebAppRegistrationUtil.java:352)
at org.wso2.carbon.dynamic.client.web.app.registration.DynamicClientWebAppRegistrationManager.registerOAuthApplication(DynamicClientWebAppRegistrationManager.java:68)
at org.wso2.carbon.dynamic.client.web.app.registration.DynamicClientWebAppRegistrationManager.initiateDynamicClientRegistration(DynamicClientWebAppRegistrationManager.java:160)
at org.wso2.carbon.dynamic.client.web.app.registration.WebAppRegistrationServerStartupObserver.completedServerStartup(WebAppRegistrationServerStartupObserver.java:36)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.notifyAfter(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:244)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.completeInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:211)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.serviceChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:288)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.registerThrottlingAgent(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:123)
at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.activate(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:514)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

master-datasources.xml

```
<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/WSO2CARBON_DB</url>
                <username>postgres</username>
                <password>postgres</password>
                <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
</datasource>


<datasource>
        <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/WSO2AM_DB</url>
                <username>postgres</username>
                <password>postgres</password>
                <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

Please help me out to solve this error. Error appear when I move WSO2AM_DB to postgres. Let me know if you need any other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be solved by configuring "defaultAutoCommit=true" property in the database configurations in master-datasource.xml.

Sample database configuration.

```
<configuration>
            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/WSO2AM_DB</url>
            <username>postgres</username>
            <password>postgres</password>
            <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
            <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
            <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks that error got solved with your fix. Now I am getting error as "[2016-05-23 05:24:09,812] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.saml.SAML2BearerGrantHandler} -  Error while getting Federated Identity Provider 
org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManagementException: Error occurred while retrieving Identity Provider information for Authenticator Property : IdPEntityId and value : localhost
"